# UWP push notifications work on Windows 10 but not Windows 11

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm following the Microsoft example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp) to send a local toast notification from my C# app (using .NET 4.8).

The following code works as expected on Windows 10 and generates a toast notification:

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
.AddText("Test notification")
.Show();
```

However on my Windows 11 test machine the notification is never shown, and execution appears to hang at the .Show() function call.

Notifications are enabled and Focus/Do Not Disturb are off on both machines.

Comment: I confirmed it works on Windows 11 22631.2115. SDK target version is 22621. UWP does not target a .NET Framework version.

Comment: Strange, I guess it's something specific to my test device then...

Comment: It also works on Windows 11 22H2 22621.1992. You can check whether your app has sent notifications in the Settings>System>Notifications  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBgmX.png